# profiling canonical play framework webapp best practices

Tags: java, profiling, playframework

Can anyone advise on best practices for monitoring and profiling apps written using play framework running as standalone (throught reverse proxy) app with mysql db in backend. May be there are some patterns or applications/modules to ease this task ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have mainly used [VisualVM](http://visualvm.java.net/) for the Java side, and for MySql I simply use the standard MySQL Administrator. There aren't any specific modules available, although if you host on playapps.net, you get a fairly decent management console.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the free [VisualVM](http://visualvm.java.net/) that comes with the JDK, I can recommend [JProfiler](http://www.ej-technologies.com/index.html) for profiling any kind of application that is running on a JVM. There's a fully functional evaluation version available.

Disclaimer: My company develops JProfiler.